# exception filter in NestJS does not catching Bad Requests with wrong json body

Tags: nestjs

my backend app written in NestJS.
I need to implement custom error handling, and I've done it with implementing ExceptionFilter.

when in most cases its working fine,
but I've noticed that when specifically I have an http request with wrong json body, the filter does not invoked and it generates standart response that looks like this:

```
{  
 "statusCode": 400,  
 "message": "Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1",  
 "error": "Bad Request" 
}
```

here is my filter class:

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        // here comes my custom response object
      });
  }
}
```

and binded it to my AppController like this:

```
@UseFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())
export class AppController{ ... }
```

and it works for other thrown HttpExceptions, just this currupt json body case is acting weird.

my guess is that specifically in this case, this Exception is already handled by nest.

is there a way to overcome this and customize my response?

Comment: I have basically the same exception filter and it does catch the 400 as well. Show to us how did bind this filter, please.

Comment: hi @MicaelLevi, 

as showed in the docu, with a decorator on my AppController, like this:

`@UseFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())`
`export class AppController{ ... }`

and it works for other thrown HttpExceptions, just this currupt json body case is weird

Comment: maybe you need to bind this at module level (like I did), but I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: tried your solution and it works, thanks! although, it should behave the same when binding on the controller level, am I right?